# Connect to UDP server

Tags: ios, sockets, udp

I'm try to create an application for iOS, where I can connect to a UDP Server and receive data from it. My situation:

1. I have a UDP server on Windows machine (IP = 192.168.1.6).
2. I have iPad (IP = 192.168.1.5);
3. UDP server sends to virtual address (IP = 239.254.1.2) and port (7125) messages, something like "HELLO!!!!! I'm here!!!!"

I need add some logic for the iOS app, where I can connect to virtual IP address (IP = 239.254.1.2) and port (7125) and receive messages "HELLO!!!!! I'm here!!!!" from UDP server.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE1:**

For UDP connection I'm use **GCDAsyncUdpSocket**

Here my code:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

- (IBAction)startStop:(id)sender {
    if (isRunning) {
        // STOP udp echo server
        [udpSocket close];

        [self logInfo:@"Stopped Udp Echo server"];
        isRunning = false;

        [portField setEnabled:YES];
        [startStopButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        // START udp echo server

        int port = [portField.text intValue];
        if (port < 0 || port > 65535) {
            portField.text = @"";
            port = 0;
        }

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![udpSocket bindToPort:7125 error:&error]) {
            [self logError:FORMAT(@"Error starting server (bind): %@", error)];
            return;
        }

        if (![udpSocket joinMulticastGroup:@"239.254.1.2" error:&error]) {
            [self logError:FORMAT(@"Error join Multicast Group: %@", error)];
            return;
        }

        if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
        {
            [udpSocket close];

            [self logError:FORMAT(@"Error starting server (recv): %@", error)];
            return;
        }

        [self logInfo:FORMAT(@"Udp Echo server started on port %hu", [udpSocket localPort])];
        isRunning = YES;

        [portField setEnabled:NO];
        [startStopButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
                                               fromAddress:(NSData *)address
                                         withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
    if (!isRunning) return;

    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (msg)
    {
        /* If you want to get a display friendly version of the IPv4 or IPv6 address, you could do this:

        NSString *host = nil;
        uint16_t port = 0;
        [GCDAsyncUdpSocket getHost:&host port:&port fromAddress:address];

        */

        [self logMessage:msg];
    }
    else
    {
        [self logError:@"Error converting received data into UTF-8 String"];
    }

    [udpSocket sendData:data toAddress:address withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

When I press "Start" button in the log I see message "Udp Echo server started on port 7125", but delegate method

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
                                                   fromAddress:(NSData *)address
                                             withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
```

never fired and application dont receive any messages from virtual IP address.
Can you help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

239.254.1.2 is a multicast address that the UDP server is sending packets to. Anyone listening on that address will receive the packets. So:

- create a UDP socket
- bind your socket to port 7125
- join the multicast group 239.254.1.2
- your app will start receiving the udp packets

Probably should just mention that UDP is connectionless protocol, i.e. you cannot connect to a UDP server.

Comment: Hello, RichardBrock
Thank you for your reply.
I'm update my question with my test source code. Can you review this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

RichardBrock was right and sample code from UPDATE1 works perfectly. Problem was with my home Network, and when I tryed this code in the work Network everything works fine!!!

Thanks you